# Dataflow Derived Columns to parse complex array

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, derived-column

can some help me to get the (nth-1) element in below complex arrays in ADF dataflow through derived columns:

```
"Ranks": {
                "3760901": [
                    6286064,
                    40635,
                    5712864,
                    567,
                    5712962,
                    711,
                    5713354,
                    -1
                ],
                "21377132011": [
                    6351134,
                    1295,
                    6351382,
                    1332,
                    6352064,
                    3212,
                    6580356,
                    -1
                ],
                "9000000000000000000": [
                    6547144,
                    8381,
                    6547914,
                    7775,
                    6548316,
                    8468,
                    6549346,
                    10031,
                    6580216,
                    -1
                ]
            }
```

result:
for 3760901 node value I am expecting 5712962,
for 21377132011 node I am expecting 3212,
for 9000000000000000000 I am expecting 10031.

the nodes are dynamic and I cant hardcode.

Comment: As per the pattern of your requirement, for 21377132011 node it should be 3212 right?

Comment: yes @RakeshGovindula. it was a mistake .Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement with the below approach.

First I have wrapped your JSON in `{}` these and given it to source of the dataflow. I have selected **Source options-> JSON settings->Single document**.

This is the **data preview of the source:**

[image]

Then I took **select transformation** to extract the columns from `Ranks` object.

In select transformation, use the `Rule based mapping`(Go to Add mapping -> Rule based mapping). Give the below configurations.

[image]

**Data preview of the select:**

[image]

Now, I took derived column to get the (n-2) element from each array columns.

Click on **Add**-> **Add Column pattern** and use the below dynamic expression.

```
($$ ? integer[])[minus(size(($$ ? integer[])),2)]
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just one more step if you can help me. How to always  take the 1st node value  from the rank object and write to a sink db..e,g if I always need the  1st value i.e 711 (it can change for a new dataset) value.

Comment: I think for this you need to check the first value of split(string(Rank object),'[') contains extracted columns names. You need to use this condition in the select transformation. its better if you raise a new question on this requirement with proper details so that I can explain clearly.